# Menu Scene runs with another Scene upon launch

Tags: unity-game-engine

how do you separate a game scene from the main menu?

I had made a 'GameScene' & 'MainMenuScene', set MainMenu as the first one(0), but they both run at the same time when I launch the game :frowning: :(

Currently they are: Both in hierarchy, the only way I had found to solve it was removing the 'GameScene' from the hierarchy- but then my MainMenuScene button which calls 'LoadScene(1)' didn't work =(

Any ideas? what can I do?
Thanks in advance everyone

Comment: Could you show us your code? Also make sure to use the correct tags. I bet your code is in `c#` ... `unityscript` is/was a JavaScript flavor like custom language previously used by Unity and is long deprecated by now ...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might not be including your second scene in your Build Index (make sure the scene has a checkmark next to its name when you click `File -> Build Settings`. If the integer scene index is causing you issues, you can also identify it by its name instead, something like `LoadScene("SceneFolderName/SceneName")`.

Comment: Hey, thanks for the comment.
My build settings contains both scenes, and my replay function is also based on the LoadScene, it works with "Scenes/GameScene" but whenever I remove the GameScene from the hierarchy / Unload it(right click unload) ==> The main menu start button does nothing.
Like the scene can't be found or something, I'm guessing it's due to that unload/removal =/

Am I missing something?